# Parse strings from Excel file for translating an Android app

Tags: android, excel

To translate my android app I have an Excel file of English, Spanish, French and many more languages each with hundreds of strings for the app.

What is the best way to separate the string names and the strings in the XML file then create new translated strings.xml documents for each language from the Excel file?  Is there a service or tool that that can automate this process?